# Prompt user after reading from piped input in Golang

Tags: go, user-input, stdin

I'm having some troubles reading from piped input, and then prompting a user for a further question afterwards. Is this possible to do?

I've created a simplified version of the program here.

I want the user to be able to pipe input in to the program instead of being prompted for it.
However, I still want to prompt them with a second question if they don't provide a specific flag in a CLI program I'm writing.

To avoid *any* prompts, the user could pass in `-y` (not shown in the program below) along with piping in the text input to skip the "are you sure?" prompt.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/AlecAivazis/survey/v2"
)

func main() {
    value := ""

    isPiped, err := isPipedInput()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if isPiped {
        _, err = fmt.Scanf("%s", &value)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        if value == "" {
            panic(fmt.Errorf("must be greater than 0"))
        }

    } else {
        err = survey.AskOne(&survey.Input{Message: "Enter value followed by [Enter]:"}, &value)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        if value == "" {
            panic(fmt.Errorf("must be greater than 0"))
        }
    }

    shouldProceed := false
    err = survey.AskOne(&survey.Confirm{Message: "Are you sure?"}, &shouldProceed)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if shouldProceed {
        fmt.Println("Proceeding!", value)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Not proceeding...", value)
    }
}

func isPipedInput() (bool, error) {
    fi, err := os.Stdin.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }

    return (fi.Mode() & os.ModeCharDevice) == 0, nil
}
```

To build:

```
go build -o main
```

First use-case that works as expected:

```
./main
? Enter value followed by [Enter]: foo
? Are you sure? Yes
Proceeding! foo
```

Second use case that does not work:

```
echo "foo" | ./main
? Are you sure? (y/N) ^[[23;256Rpanic: EOF

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        /main.go:40 +0x2b0
^[[8;23R%
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you're trying to do isn't supported with Survey

https://github.com/AlecAivazis/survey#faq

> survey aims to support most terminal emulators; it expects support for ANSI escape sequences. This means that reading from piped stdin or writing to piped stdout is not supported, and likely to break your application in these situations. See [337](https://github.com/AlecAivazis/survey/pull/337#issue-581351617)

From the looks of your code, it doesn't seem like you really need Survey if you're just prompting the user for input. Might be best to implement the prompt yourself.

Comment: Interesting! I missed that faq statement. I've been in the weeds a bit and have been trying a combination of other things. I originally didn't have survey, but it's hard to remember now. I will try it without survey. We are using it in other spots and I like the rendering it provides.